# How to create dropdown splitted button (like Mail.app)?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Mail.app at Mac OS have cool dropdown buttons at toolbars. It is not simple dropdown button, that button is splitted to 2 parts (button and dropdown list). How can I create such type of button with menu so it have 2 actions (menu and click)?

Button:

[image: Dropdown]

Menu:

[image: Dropdown with list]

Answer (score 0):

I assume Apple uses a `NSSegmentedControl` object there. One for the flag, one for the arrow.

To replicate this behavior, add a segmentedControl in Interface Builder with two segments and set its Mode to `Momentary`.

Then add your images or titles and set the width of the second segment to an appropriate value. 
[image]

This was my quick outcome:

[image]